Transmission Lines and Waveguides - How to calculate Intrinsic Impedance?
I have come across a problem when calculating the attenuation due to conductor losses for circular cross sections:

A circular copper waveguide has a radius of 0.4 cm and is filled with a dielectric material having
Er = 1.5 (dielectric value) and tan δ = 0.0002. Identify the first four propagating modes and their cutoff frequencies.
For the dominant mode, calculate the total attenuation at 20 GHz.

I know that the equation to solve for attenuation due to conductor losses is:
$$ \alpha_c = \frac{R_s}{a.k.n.\beta(k_c^2+\frac{k^2}{p_{11}}-1)} $$
However, I am having issues solving the intrinsic impedance n. How do I solve for this variable?

PROBABLY the n is really the Greek letter that looks like n, usually used for the impedance of free space E/H = sqrt(mu0/epsilon0). OP will have to consult the textbook that the equation came from but my guess is that epsilon0 needs to be replaced by the permittivity of the dielectric.
